# How do I get the python package "gtk"?

Tags: python, image, gtk

I can't import it right now, but my library imports it.

I don't want the full Windows gtk thing. I just want the package that can be imported by this script:  http://www.koders.com/python/fid798D591F71AC2C5F462B7BFFF0D84E1EA8D5759F.aspx?s=timer

Comment: You want "the full windows gtk thing". pyGTK cannot work without GTK installed (duh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the [PyGTK website](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.22/) and choose the all-in-one .msi that matches your Python version. Save it and then open the .msi to install GTK for Python.

Comment: that all-in-one package is simply awesome. Just a few months ago I tried for *hours* to get the old GTK installers to work with Python2.7 and failed. Now it took 3 minutes.